# replace web.config file with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, iis, web-config

We are running PHP site on IIS 8. We migrated it from Linux to windows and transformed .htaccess to web.config using URL rewrite feature in IIS.

Is there any way to replace web.config from the site's root folder with .htaccess. We don't want to use web.config in the IIS site.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.htaccess` is a file format used by Apache only. It's not possible to use this file when using another webserver.